# Create animated gif from a set of jpeg images

Tags: windows, animated-gif

I need something that can be scripted on windows 7. This image will be used in banners.

Comment: does it need to be jpeg? jpeg->anim gif is likely to have unwanted flickery artifacts with worse compression ratio. you should use lossless -> gif, or gif->gif for the best quality results.

Comment: @tenfour - although what you have pointed out is perfectly valid, it's not necessarily a rule of thumb. Much more important is that the frames share similar colors, because if they don't, the palette of maximum 256 colors of a GIF image that is shared between frames will produce crappy results, regardless of the input format and will often leave people wondering "why did it come out grainy ?!"

Comment: Using images `IMG-001.jpg`, `IMG-002.jpg`, and so on (with `3` digits), showing `4` images per second, you get the result as a GIF by simply using the following command: `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 4 -i "IMG-%03d.jpg" Output.gif`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do this with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

First convert the images to a video:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.avi
```

(This will convert the images from the current directory (named image1.jpg, image2.jpg...) to a video file named video.avi.)

Then convert the avi to a gif:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -pix_fmt rgb24 -loop_output 0 out.gif
```

<sub>You can get [windows binaries for ffmpeg here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).</sub>

---

You can also do a similar thing with [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu). See [Encoding from multiple input image files](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-images.html).

I think the command line would be something like:

```
mplayer mf://*.jpg -mf w=800:h=600:type=jpg -vf scale=160:120 -vo gif89a:fps=3:output=out.gif
```

(Where 800 & 600 are your source width and height and 160 & 120 are the target width and height.out.gif is your target file name)

---

I've just tested both of these and they both work fine. However I got much better results from mplayer as I was able to specify the resolution and framerate. Your milage may vary and I'm sure you could find more options for ffmpeg if you looked.

Comment: Using the recent version of mplayer, it just prints out its manpage.

Comment: this has a good google search rating, so if you want to prefix numbers with zeros, use `%04d` (number 4 would use 4 number positions prefixed with 0)

Comment: no file found with name `image1d.jpg` ! trying using cmd

Comment: Brilliant answer, just so anyone trying to use it currently is aware the new flag for the .avi to .gif conversion is `-loop`, with an option of 0 for infinite loop. Also I think the rgb profile flag (not that I know anything about colour profiles made my thumbnail have a blue grid of dots over it

Comment: You can indeed just use the first command and output to GIF directly by changing the file extension given in the command. Moreover, you may set a frame rate, e.g. `-framerate 1`, `-framerate 20` or `-framerate 1/5`.

Comment: Doesn't converting to avi degrade quality since avi uses lossy compression?

Comment: @caw I tried that. But ffmpeg is introducing some artifacts in the gif. Some dots/blobs on the video. Any idea why?

Answer (score 135):

[Simon P Stevens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688962/1349518) almost got me there:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.avi
ffmpeg -i video.avi -pix_fmt rgb24 -loop_output 0 out.gif
```

Let's see if we can neaten this up.

Going via an avi is unnecessary. A `-pix_fmt` of `rgb24` is invalid, and the `-loop_output` option prevents looping, which I don't want. We get:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg out.gif
```

My input pictures are labeled with a zero-padded 3-digit number and I have 30 of them (image_001.jpg, image_002.jpg, ...), so I need to fix the format specifier

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image_%003d.jpg out.gif
```

My input pictures are from my phone camera, they are way too big! I need to scale them down.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image_%003d.jpg -vf scale=531x299 out.gif
```

I also need to rotate them 90 degrees clockwise

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image_%003d.jpg -vf scale=531x299,transpose=1 out.gif
```

This gif will play with zero delay between frames, which is probably not what we want. Specify the framerate of the input images

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 9 -i image_%003d.jpg -vf scale=531x299,transpose=1 out.gif
```

The image is just a tad too big, so I'll crop out 100 pixels of sky. The transpose makes this tricky, I use the post-rotated x and y values:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 9 -i image_%003d.jpg -vf scale=531x299,transpose=1,crop=299,431,0,100 out.gif
```

The final result - I get to share my mate's awesome facial expression with the world:

[image: Example of an animated gif created with ffmpeg]

Comment: %003d ffmpeg replaces this with path - `image_C:/user/...`

Comment: Great answer!  Too bad it stops short of 2-step palette optimization: https://superuser.com/a/556031/142943

Comment: In case your image index do not start at zero, use the `-start_number xxx` option. https://superuser.com/a/666994/999889

Comment: My images were synthetic (i.e. plots) and for somes reason unknown to me when I used `ffmpeg` there were some yellow lines in the resulting gif file; though, I didn't encounter this problem when I used ImageMagick `convert` command instead.

Comment: what does image2 represent?

Comment: `image2` is the name of the ffmpeg demuxer (the bit that reads the input). `image2` provides the file globbing used in `-i` and knows how to read the files as a video source. See http://manpages.org/ffmpeg

Answer (score 60):

With ImageMagick:

```
convert *.png a.gif
```

Comment: also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508945/imagemagick-animated-gif-size-optimization

Comment: I had quality issues from using .png files (because of transparency and layering) which were fixed by using .jpg instead

Comment: You can use `-delay` to set the duration each image is shown. Note that the value is given in 1/100 seconds, i.e. `-delay 100` results in a rate of one frame per second.

Comment: Commands like `convert -delay 100 *.jpg Output.gif` work fine, but produce larger file sizes than `ffmpeg` does, it seems, even when using `-layers optimize`.

Answer (score 15):

The **ffmpeg** to **.avi** and **.avi** to **.gif** worked, but the only thing to note is that your images must be named in perfect increasing numeric order to work, with no gaps. I cooked up a quick python script to rename all of my images accordingly so that this **ffmpeg** recipe would work:

```
import os

files = [ f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('.',f)) and f.endswith('.jpg') ]
for i, file in enumerate(sorted(files)):
    os.rename(file, 'image%03d.jpg' % i)
```

And then I stumbled upon a much simpler approach than **ffmpeg** for doing the conversion, which is simply using ImageMagick's command line convert tool like this

```
convert image%03d.jpg[0-198] animated_gif.gif
```

Doesn't get much simpler than that folks.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/3289840

Comment: _"images must be named in perfect increasing numeric order"_ - I guess you do not know about `-pattern_type glob`, it allows to use files with any names as input, for example, to convert all pngs in current directory to gif: `ffmpeg -framerate 1/10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' output.gif`

Comment: @LissanroRayen, `-pattern_type` would be really great if it could be conjuncted with *.jpg source files somethow, not just *.png.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the answers of Simon P Stevens and dwurf I came up with this simplified solution:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1 -i image%d.jpg video.gif
```

This results in a rate of 1 second per image.  Adjust the `framerate` value according to your needs.

Answer (score 12):

I'd just like to add to [dwurf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29542944/448357)'s answer, that this will generate a gif with the standard 256-colors palette, which does not look very visually pleasing.

I've found [two](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) [blog-posts](https://medium.com/@colten_jackson/doing-the-gif-thing-on-debian-82b9760a8483) and adapted them to my needs, in order to improve the visual quality by using a custom palette for your animation:

Generate the color palette:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg -vf scale=900:-1:sws_dither=ed,palettegen palette.png
```

Convert images into a regular video with the desired framerate, because the third command only worked with a single input video and not a bunch of images

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1.2 -i image%d.jpg video.flv
```

Now convert the generated video with the generated palette into a more beautiful gif:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=1.2,scale=900:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" video.gif
```