# Imagemagick animated gif size optimization

Tags: php, image, compression, imagemagick, gif

I am use this code to resize and save a animated gif (php):

```
system("convert *originalfile* -resize *size* -coalesce *newfile*);
```

Once done the filesize is quite large. Usually larger than the original even! What can I do to reduce the file size?

I used `convert $completeMiff -dither none -matte -depth 8 -deconstruct  -layers optimizePlus -colors 32  $optimizedFile_16` and the file gets even bigger???

Comment: This happens even when you are resizing the image smaller I take it?

Comment: What format are your original files in?

Comment: The originals are animated gifs. Yes Philip

Answer (score 7):

Add `-layers optimize`

```
system("convert *originalfile* -resize *size* -coalesce -layers optimize *newfile*");
```

That worked well enough for me, when I faced this issue.  [Looks like there are some more advanced options discussed here as well](http://studio.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13339&start=0)

Comment: I tried adding that option, the file is still larger than the original, even though I resized it to smaller dimensions. Weird...