# Using saveGif with graphics object in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, gif, p5.js

I'm trying to save a series of images into a gif. I am trying to do this entirely in P5 without any other libraries or server side infrastructure. I got saveGif to work if I look at the main canvas, but as soon as I try with a graphics object, it breaks. I read using createCanvas multiple times can cause issues, but maybe I am supposed to do instance mode for this?

Anyways, this is what I'm trying right now:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400); // Set up a canvas
    // Example images to simulate Frame.frames
    let exampleFrames = [
        'path/to/image1.jpg',
        'path/to/image2.jpg',
        'path/to/image3.jpg'
    ];

    select("#saveGifButton").mouseClicked(function() {
        createGIF(exampleFrames);
    });
}

function createGIF(framePaths) {
    var images = [];
    var sumWidth = 0;
    var sumHeight = 0;

    // Load images and calculate dimensions
    for (var i = 0; i < framePaths.length; i++) {
        images[i] = loadImage(framePaths[i], img => {
            sumWidth += img.width;
            sumHeight += img.height;
        });
    }

    var picWidth = sumWidth / framePaths.length;
    var picHeight = sumHeight / framePaths.length;
    var tempGraphics = createGraphics(picWidth, picHeight);


    tempGraphics.saveGif("MyGif", images.length, {
                'units': 'frames'
            });
    for (var i = 0; i < framePaths.length; i++) {
        tempGraphics.clear();
        tempGraphics.image(images[i], 0, 0, picWidth, picHeight);
    }

    
    tempGraphics.remove();
}
```

So, when I tried with the graphics item, it gives this error:

```
 p5.js says: [p5.js, line 74975] 

Cannot read property of undefined. Check the line number in error and make sure the variable which is being operated is not undefined.

 + More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_property#what_went_wrong
p5.js:59804 ┌[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:74975:27] 
     Error at line 74975 in addElement()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:75050:18] 
     Called from line 75050 in _main.default.createP()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:84471:32] 
     Called from line 84471 in _class._callee$()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:50400:25] 
     Called from line 50400 in tryCatch()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:50594:30] 
     Called from line 50594 in Generator.invoke [as _invoke]()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:50454:29] 
     Called from line 50454 in prototype.<computed> [as next]()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:84122:32] 
     Called from line 84122 in asyncGeneratorStep()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:84141:17] 
     Called from line 84141 in _next()
└[http://127.0.0.1:5500/lib/p5.js:84146:15] 
     Called from line 84146 in ()
```

GPT and googling failed me. I have no idea how else to handle this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see [Exporting canvas as GIF/PNG in p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232063/exporting-canvas-as-gif-png-in-p5js)? This isn't a [mcve] so it's rather hard to say what the problem might be. Please make sure all variables are defined and the snippet is runnable. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to give more context, but I guess I could make it more minimally reproducible. 
And, yeah I saw that, but it requires either the CCapture.js or Gif.js library, and I am trying to do this without adding another library.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68875901/6243352) in that thread is entirely p5, with no dependencies. When you say `saveGif` breaks, what do you mean? Is there an error or some unexpected behavior? Looking forward to your reproducible [edit].

Comment: I believe this is more reproducible. The saveGif only works when you are attempting it on the main canvas, when you try to use it on a graphics object, it throws the error I described. 
Ideally, I'm trying to have this be a download button for users, so the pre 1.5 idea is unfortunately not feasible. 
Can you let me know if this is reproducible enough?

Comment: Yeah, this seems pretty good. Thanks. I guess I'm not quite clear why you need the `createGraphics` call though. Can't you just draw the images one by one to create the gif? `loadImage` is async, so any code that accesses `images[i]` needs to be chained from the callback, I would think. I don't see `tempGraphics.image(images[i], 0, 0, picWidth, picHeight);` working. Which line throws the error shown here?

Comment: The tempGraphics.saveGif is what is throwing the error. I want to make the gif offscreen, with the series of images. I am using the main canvas for other operations, and would like to not stop user input to create the Gif.